# How to put two spry menu bars with different characteristics on the same page

Tags: menubar, spry, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS5. I'm able to create one sprymenu with no problems; it works well. When I try to add another one, Dreamweaver doesn't create another "spry elements" folder. The second menu just takes the attributes of the first, e.g. for font face and font size.

How can I get the second menu to be completely editable and disconnected from the first? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, working strictly as a designer.  The approach is relatively simple.  Essentially, you want to copy the existing SpryAssets, rename the new copy, and use it as a new, independent Spry menu.  To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to Widows Explorer
2. Locate and copy Spry Assets of the existing Spry menu and past it in your website folder (you will now have two identical Spry Assets folders next to each other).
3. Change the name of the copied file to SpryAssets2 (or another appropriate name)
4. Click and open your new SpryAssets2 file
   Identify and rename SpryMenuBar to *SpryMenuBar2*
   Identify and rename SpryMenuBarVertical.css (or SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css) to *SpryMenuBarVertical2.css* (or SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css, as the case may be).
   Close
5. In Dreamweaver, open the page where you wish to use the new Spry Menu files. Insert a Spry Menu or use the one already there (this is the OLD Spry menu file).
6. In the SCC Style panel, locate and click on the SCC (SpryMenuBarVertical.css)
7. Attach the new CSS sheet to it: go to Browse; find the SpryMenuBarVertical.css2 and attach it

This should do it; then edit the menu as you wish. Other pages of the website will NOT be affected.

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of the css for the menu and rename the copy element IDs with something meaningful for the 2nd menu.  It's time consuming but very possible.  I'd also put a BIG space with comments saying which set of styles goes with which menu.